# Android Toolbar with Spinner with white text and white popup background?

Tags: android, spinner, toolbar

I've been trying to add a spinner to my toolbar but failed to achieve what I want.

This is what I have so far.

[image]
[image]

As you can see on the screen shots, the Spinner's selected text color is black (I want it to be white) while the popup has a white background with text color black (this is ok).

Here's my code.

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_date_range_white_24dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/date_range"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:entries="@array/date_range_options"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

If I change the Toolbar and add app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" like below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```

I get the white text color of the spinners selected text but the popup background becomes dark with white text color as well.

I want to have while text color in the selected and with a white popup background with black text.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a theme to do this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/date_range"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:entries="@array/date_range_options"
                android:theme="@style/spinnerStyle
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

And then in your styles file

```
<style name="spinnerStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white_text</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white_text</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white_text</item>
</style>
```

Replace @color/white_text with whatever color you want to use.

Comment: hi. i tried your suggestion but it didn't work. it shows the same effect as the one in the screen shots above.

Comment: Strange maybe because it's in a toolbar. That oddly works for me. Are you using a custom adapter for your spinner. If so in the getView method you could do this  TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        deviceName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white_text));

That's assuming you're using the default layout for the spinner (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)

Comment: No, I'm not using an adapter. This is all on xml.

Comment: What api level are you targeting?